# Why are the number of edits displayed besides a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

What is the reason for displaying the number of times a comment is edited by the commenter?

[image: Screenshot of a comment]

Comment: maybe transparency? sometimes replies to comments seem weird, and recognizing that they have been edited clears things up. Also funny things happen when a comment was "upvoted" and changed after that.

Comment: What **exactly** are you talking about? A screenshot would help make sure we are all on the same page as you.

Comment: I don't think there's a number showing how many times a comment has been edited. Posting this so I can edit it multiple times... Edit 1; Edit 2; Edit 3; Edit 4, I don't see a number. Does anyone else? Edit 5, Edit 6: Oh, the number's in a tooltip.

Comment: If you are talking about the number to the left of a comment, that is the number of upvotes on the comment. You have to hover over the edit image on the right to see the number of times the comment has been edited.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire - the only indication that your comment was edited is that little pencil at the end of it (whatever number of edits).

Comment: why did someone upvote this comment? Seeing that it has been edited might reveal that something else was upvoted then...

Comment: @Oded: he probably means that pencil, mouseover shows the number of times.

Comment: I would say that seeing the number of edits a comment has gone through gives you an idea of how much it changed from its original. Not a bad thing to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gives you a *slight* idea of how much change has been made to the comment since it was first posted.
This way, even though you don't have access to a full version history of the comment, you still know if it was modified and how many times it was modified.

Don't overthink this.

It is simply a *"nice to have"* feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking the same, but still had curiosity to know if it had some special purpose.